# Crawling popular video barrages from Bilibili, the URL request parameters are different

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, md5

There is a w_rid parameter in the url parameter of station B. This parameter was found to be encrypted by md5 through debugging. The w_rid parameter was constructed by myself. It is not consistent with the w_rid parameter in the url of station B, but this parameter was constructed by myself.the response data can still be requested, why is this?
This is the parameter w_rid in the URL of station B: f2b3fb3807eb99bbc84c86fce9e028fd
The latter is the parameter I constructed myself: a2eddf288941afe50d99eaa20bdeedba
These two parameters are not the same after being encrypted by md5.